# ASP Net Core multiple environment publishing

Tags: .net-core, deployment, octopus

Coming from the .NET MVC world, I am confused on how .NET Core deals with multi-environment deployments. (Dev, Test, Production)

The tech used here are Bamboo (Build Server) + Octopus Deploy (CD).

.NET Core appears to be using appsettings instead, and web.config is only used for IIS Hosting.

Upon reading some guides, which suggests to add an Environment Variable "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" to the project to define the environment currently in.

This is the command I used to build in Bamboo.
`dotnet publish -c Test ${bamboo.build.working.directory}\HelloWorld.sln`

Questions...
1. I have appsettings.json, appsettings.Test.json, appsettings.Production.json.
   It looks like the app knows which appsettings file to read from, based on the 
   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value.

2. How can I tell Octopus to use the correct file based on the environment I am deploying to?

Comment: I would ask you - why do you have files per environment? Surely you need just the one file and transform it using Octopus as part of the deployment, so your settings are correct for the environment you're deploying to.

Comment: it appears that's how asp net core handles multi-environment deployments. i was under the same impression, that it could be transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Having a variable and multiple config files packaged up make things overly complicated, especially if you're using Octopus Deploy.

The only reason for having multiple `.environment.json` files is because these are probably held in source control and they have their values already set - so environment variables are probably all coming from the source code, rather than the release manager. Otherwise, they'd be identical files and Octopus would still be transforming them (which makes them redundant)

My advice would be to move to a single file, and move the variables into Octopus Deploy. Remove the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and you only need one file `appSettings.json`, which can be transformed during deployment to whatever environment.

ASP.NET Core Web Applications - [Octopus Deploy Documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/asp.net-core-web-application-deployments)

Hope this helps

Comment: We didn't want to save the variables in the Octopus Deploy, so it would be easier to migrate to Azure DevOps in the future.